# Keys Press Twice in Ubuntu Activities Overview

Tags: gnome, 22.04, activities-overview

When I try to type in activities overview, the first key gets typed twice. This only happens in activities overview.
example- When I type "Ubuntu", it gets typed as "UUbuntu"

- I've encountered this problem with different keyboards
- Version: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug with the dash-to-dock Gnome extension:

https://github.com/micheleg/dash-to-dock/issues/1855

As a temporary workaround, try disabling `Show overview on startup` under `Appearance` in dash-to-dock settings and log back in.